# tkinter: imagetk image in a canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm missing something simple here... I'm trying to insert an image in a canvas,

```
photoconn = Image.open(giffname)
photoconn = photoconn.resize((w0*self.resize/100,h*self.resize/100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photoconn)
pc.append(photoImg)
self.cv.create_image(10, 10, anchor=NW, image=photoImg)
```

and I get the dreaded **_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage39" doesn't exist**

Yet I memorize the image in the global pc array, and the debugger shows that the variables seem ok, with photoconn being a `<PIL.GifImagePlugin.GifImageFile 0x260fab8; len=28>`, and photoImg being a `<PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage 0x260fb48; len=12>`.

... what am I missing?

Comment: What line of code is producing that error?

Comment: the last one, Bryan: the create_image

Comment: OK OK ... big mistake I did - I just read somewhere how it is a BIG mistake to create new windows using Tk() (what I did here), instead of Toplevel() ... that solved the problem . sorry guys...

Comment: It is not such a mistake, it is rather quite common. The mistake is to call several time Tk(). This error (fail to retrieve ressource on name) might come from Tk not finding data which can arise if ImageTk and canvas does not share the same interpreter.